# jQuery button does not fire click event consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a nav bar in jQuery Mobile defined like this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-id="foo2">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a data-icon="arrow-l" id='prevPage'>Wstecz</a></li>
          <li><a data-icon="home" id='mainLink'><span id='mainButton'>Quizz.pl</span></a></li>
          <li><a data-icon="arrow-r" id='nextPage'>Dalej</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want nextPage button to do some work, so i bind it

```
$("#nextPage").bind("click", nextPage);
```

And here, strange thing happens. In latest Firefox when i click the button sometimes it does nothing, sometimes i does not fire click event and it seems like it didn't get "unclicked", so when i scroll page content is selected. Sometimes it fires click properly.

Anyone had this issue and know how to handle it properly?

Comment: You can see a working demo here: http://quizz.pl/#!/quizy/najnowsze/strona/3

Comment: which version of jquery you are using, and please don't create demo on that site, use jsfiddle jibin codepen etc.

Comment: You may not want to use bind. Consider using the .on() function instead. jQuery 1.7 and later suggest this practice.

Comment: Make sure you're embedding your event listener at the bottom of your page or enclosed in a `$(document).ready` function. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I've tried on like @td-edge suggesteed and it seems to work now... Can you pls reproduce if it works fine? I needed to clear cache before seeing result.

Comment: Wrap your event listeners in `pagecreate` event, don't use `ready`.